# I am trying to delete a node from Linked List ,but some run time error is there

Tags: pointers, linked-list

why is it not printing value of current->val in the while loop,

```
 while(i<=count-B-1)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        current=current->next;
        cout<<current->val<<endl;
        i++;
    }
```

Here is the full code :

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
ListNode* Solution::removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* A, int B) {
    int count=0;
    ListNode *current=A;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current=current->next;
    }
    if(B>count)
    {
        return A->next;
    }
    if(A->next=NULL)
    {
        return A->next;
    }
    current = A;
    int i=0;
    while(i<=count-B-1)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        current=current->next;
        cout<<current->val<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    // cout<<current->val<<endl;
    current->next=current->next->next;
    return A;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The reason why the loop doesn't loop, is that you unintentionally reduced the list to just one node:

  ```
  if(A->next=NULL)
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if(A->next==NULL)
  ```

  A good compiler / IDE should give a warning about this.
- When `B` is `count`, then the first node should be removed, so change

  ```
  if(B>count)
  ```

  to:

  ```
  if(B>=count)
  ```
- The `while` loop should make one less iteration. So change:

  ```
  while(i<=count-B-1)
  ```

  to:

  ```
  while(i<count-B-1)
  ```